# How to divide two lengths and get a result as an integer?

Tags: calculations, lengths

I have a problem dividing two lenghts and getting a result as an integer. I was trying to use this package:

`\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}`

It didn't really work for me. I tried it multiple ways, but it still didnt work.

Can you help me with an alternative way?

Comment: Should the integer be the largest integer less than or equal to the quotient?

Comment: [this answer at LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2712#p10691) might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr`, but this rounds rather than truncate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\getlengthratio}[2]{%
  \number\numexpr
    \dimexpr#1\relax
     /
    \dimexpr#2\relax
  \relax}

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

There are \getlengthratio{\textwidth}{\parindent} parindents in a line

\setcounter{test}{\getlengthratio{\textwidth}{\parindent}}

The same number: \thetest

\end{document}
```

A different approach, where you can choose between floor, ceil and round, is with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlengthratio}{mm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { floor ( \dim_to_fp:n { #1 } / \dim_to_fp:n { #2 } , 0 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

There are \getlengthratio{\textwidth}{\parindent} parindents in a line

\setcounter{test}{\getlengthratio{\textwidth}{\parindent}}

The same number: \thetest

\end{document}
```

[image]